# How to add extra row in tableview except for two cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row

This struct in HomeVC:

```
struct JsonData{

var name: String = ""
var categoryname: String = ""
var customerdetails: [cDetails] = [cDetails]()

init(name: String, categoryname: String, customerdetails: [cDetails]){
self.name = name
self.categoryname = categoryname
self.customerdetails = customerdetails
}
}
struct cDetails{
var dValue: String = ""

init(dValue: String) {
self.dValue = dValue

}
}
```

here i am able to add extra row for whole categoryname, but in that categoryname except 1st and last bname i dont need extra row, how todo that.

i mean `mobile postpaid` is categoryname and tableview content is `bname` values, in that tableview 1st and last bname i dont need extra row, how to do that,

here is my code:

```
 var selectedBiller: JsonData?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        self.rowCount = selectedBiller?.customerdetails.count ?? 0

        if selectedBiller?.categoryname == "Mobile Postpaid"{

         if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" && selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)"
            {
            return selectedBiller?.customerdetails.count ?? 0
            }//if
         else{
        return  self.rowCount! + 1
         } 
        }
      i give like this also i am getting extra row
        else{
            return selectedBiller?.customerdetails.count ?? 0
        }
    }
    return 1
}
```

here for all mobile indexpath i am getting extra row but except 1st and last indexpath i need

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell

    if self.rowCount! - 1 >= indexPath.row
        {
    if let value = selectedDetail?.customerdetails[indexPath.row] {
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = value.dValue
    } else {
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing data"
    }
}
else
{
    cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
}
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you want to add a new cell below when user click of tableViewCell, but have some constraint like if user click on vodaphonepostpaid(fetch) and airtelpostpaid(fetch)  you dont want, right ?

Comment: @SGDev, sorry, i confused every one, i have edited my post. please help, i am able to add extra cell for whole categoryname == "Mobile Postpaid" but in that category except `vodaphonepostpaid(fetch) and airtelpostpaid(fetch)`  bname values i need to add extra row

Comment: still you are confusing me, simple you don't need a a cell in case of `vodaphonepostpaid(fetch) and airtelpostpaid(fetch)`?

Comment: @SGDev Oops really, yes, if  vodaphonepostpaid(fetch) and airtelpostpaid(fetch) then i dont need    `cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"` this, only i need         `cell?.searchTextfield.text = value.dValue`

Comment: why do you use &&, used || operator. `if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" && selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)"`.

Comment: @SGDev, actually i dont know where to add thats why i added there, bcoz of your mentioned above condition i dont need extra count

Comment: used this line inside the numberOfRowsInSection  `if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" || selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)` instead of `if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" && selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)`. it will work for you

Comment: @SGDev, thank you sooo much you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this line inside the numberOfRowsInSection

```
if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" || selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)
```

instead of

```
if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" && selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch).
```

it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line -

```
         if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" && selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)"
```

to

```
         if selectedBiller?.name == "vodaphonepostpaid(fetch)" || selectedBiller?.name == "airtelpostpaid(fetch)"
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the comments, it was under show more